# Modules are not being found when migrating from CRA to Vite

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules, create-react-app, vite

I am trying to migrate my application from create react app to Vite. I followed this tutorial article on how to do it. So far, I have deleted the node_modules folder, made the following changes:

[changes to package.json:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFg6n.png)

then ran `npm i`, then made these changes to

[I actually had to replace "start" with "dev" for this one to get it to work:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahEwy.png)

I then moved public/index.html to index.html (project root folder).

[changes to index.html:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZrkV.png)

[changes to index.html:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlp90.png)

[I added this vite.config.jsx file:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiMcP.png)

Lastly I replaced all .js file extensions with .jsx. But now when I enter `npm run dev` it is telling me it can't find multiple different modules. I get a message like this:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '/Users/gtrman97/Documents/code/coding-projects/project/node_modules/esbuild/' imported from /Users/gtrman97/Documents/code/coding-projects/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js
```

Out of curiosity, I commented out the `import 'esbuild';` line in the cli.js file but got the same error with a different module:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '/Users/gtrman97/Documents/code/coding-projects/project/node_modules/resolve/' imported from /Users/gtrman97/Documents/code/coding-projects/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to migrate from CRA to vite, for me, is to create a vite app and copy all the components I created and install all of the dependencies I have on the CRA app. And boom, it just works. At least for my typescript CRA project. (And by examing git diffs, not surprisingly, only the `package.json` file changed.)

Comment: That's what I started to do but I was pretty far along with CRA. I suppose doing that would have a higher chance of working even though it's kind of a pain.

Comment: Me personally don't know any of webpack/CRA or Vite stuff works, and don't care either, as long as I can run my application : )

Comment: BTW, vite is indeed much faster than webpack. As the project grows and I noticed significant compile time increase. That's why I moved to vite as well